# Show Two Letter State Code on Mapbox Instead of out of the box Abbreviation Provided

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I would like to show the two letter state code on states in the United States of America in mapbox. I've taken a look at the `state-label` editor shown here:

[image: mapbox screenshot]

The closest option is `iso_3166_2` but this prepends all the labels with a `US-` like `US-OH`. Is there a way to just have `OH`? any information would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we can use string operators to modify the string as well.
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/

In your case, `slice(coalesce(iso_3166_2), 3, 5)` seems to work

[image]